# Creating a foreign key in Postgresgl gives this error: ERROR: AccessExclusiveLock required to add toast table

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys

I'm trying to fix a problem regarding creation of foreign keys for hours now.
I have a database in Postgres and have added a new table. Next I want to create a foreign key from each table to this new table. For most tables this went without a problem. But some tables give this issue:

```
STATEMENT:  alter table tenant.contactperson add constraint FKljvqy3xgfjo8gj4cuvjawhwtw foreign key (tenant_id) references tenant.tenant;
ERROR:  AccessExclusiveLock required to add toast table.
```

I tried locking the table in a Transaction but same message. Does anyone have clue what this may cause?

Comment: Please show the table definitions and other data to reproduce the problem. Check for data corruption. Did you modify catalog tables?

Comment: Also: Is this DB in use? Is there any chance that a long-running or orphaned thread is holding a conflicting lock?